# Why is there a segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am trying to solve this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/ffxabb/20200309_challenge_383_easy_necklace_matching/

where you check if words can be rearranged by moving the last letter of one to the front(can be done multiple times) and I keep getting a segmentation fault on line 37.  Does anyone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void shift(string, int);

bool same_necklace(string a, string b)
{
    if(strlen(a) != strlen(b))
    {
        printf("false\n");
        return false;
    }
    int n = strlen(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        shift(a, n);
        if(strcmp(a, b) == 0)
        {
            printf("true\n");
            return true;
        }
    }
    printf("false\n");
    return false;
}

void shift(string a, int n)
{
    char output[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        output[i] = a[(i+1) % n];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = output[i];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    same_necklace("nicole", "icolen");
    same_necklace("nicole", "lenico");
    same_necklace("nicole", "coneli");
    same_necklace("aabaaaaabaab", "aabaabaabaaa");
    same_necklace("abc", "cba");
    same_necklace("xxyyy", "xxxyy");
    same_necklace("xyxxz", "xxyxz");
    same_necklace("x", "x");
    same_necklace("x", "xx");
    same_necklace("x", "");
    same_necklace("", "");
}
```

Comment: `a[i] = output[i];` UB to attempt to change string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store values to a string literal, which is read-only memory on modern OSes.

To fix it make a copy of the string you're going to shift before-hand. Remember to make room for the null-terminator and free your memory after you're done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void shift(string, int);

bool same_necklace(string a, string b)
{
    int n = strlen(a);
    a = memcpy(malloc(n + 1), a, n + 1);
    if(strlen(a) != strlen(b))
    {
        printf("false\n");
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        shift(a, n);
        if(strcmp(a, b) == 0)
        {
            printf("true\n");
            return true;
        }
    }
    printf("false\n");
    free(a);
    return false;
}
void shift(string a, int n)
{
    char output[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        output[i] = a[(i+1) % n];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = output[i];
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    same_necklace("nicole", "icolen");
    same_necklace("nicole", "lenico");
    same_necklace("nicole", "coneli");
    same_necklace("aabaaaaabaab", "aabaabaabaaa");
    same_necklace("abc", "cba");
    same_necklace("xxyyy", "xxxyy");
    same_necklace("xyxxz", "xxyxz");
    same_necklace("x", "x");
    same_necklace("x", "xx");
    same_necklace("x", "");
    same_necklace("", "");
}
```